# After Receiving an signal, which exception handler invoked first?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, signals

Let's say we have a program in C that uses the `sleep()` function.

The program executes and goes to sleep. Then we type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to send a `SIGINT` signal to the process.

We know that the default action upon receipt of a `SIGINT` is to terminate the process, we also know that the sleep function returns prematurely whenever the sleeping process receives a signal that is not ignored.

After we type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, does the `sleep()` function return first or the process gets terminated first?

Answer (score 1):

The default action of `SIGINT` is to terminate the process according to the documentation (taken here from `signal(7)` on OpenBSD).

```
These signals are defined in the file <signal.h>:

Name         Default Action       Description
SIGHUP       terminate process    terminal line hangup
SIGINT       terminate process    interrupt program
```

Termination should, in theory, not give a process any chance to execute
any more code. A simple litmus test may help to show what is going on
(but does not prove that no code from the process is executed following
an unhandled `SIGINT`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void sigint(int sig)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "got INT\n");
}

void warnexit(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "atexit\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    atexit(warnexit);
    //signal(SIGINT, sigint);
    fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", getpid());
    sleep(640);
    fprintf(stderr, "ouch!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

With the `signal(...)` handler commented out, a <kbd>control+c</kbd>
exits the program; there is no indication the `atexit` handler nor
`ouch` line are run:

```
$ make sleepint
egcc -O2 -pipe    -o sleepint sleepint.c 
$ ./sleepint
31761
^C
$
```

With the `signal(...)` handler uncommented, the remainder of the code is reached:

```
$ make sleepint
egcc -O2 -pipe    -o sleepint sleepint.c 
$ ./sleepint 
64094
^Cgot INT
ouch!
atexit
$
```

Note however that `SIGINT` handling is in practice very complicated: shells and other processes will routinely have `SIGINT` handlers (otherwise the shell would exit, which could be bad), pressing <kbd>control+c</kbd> may not send a signal to the foreground process group (a program could put the terminal into raw mode with e.g. the ncurses `cbreak()` call and would instead see a `ETX` key), and [different shells do different things](https://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html) when a complex command is hit with a <kbd>control+c</kbd>. Also with `sigaction(2)` one can use the `SA_RESTART` flag to change how various system calls behave...